# Ubuntu server connecting to L2TP VPN

Tags: server, 14.04, vpn

I am trying to connect to a VPN from my ubuntu 14.04LTS server.

This is a fresh install.

I can't seem to find a guide on how to connect to the VPN from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a little dig around, and found [this nice tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That would be plagiarism ;)

Comment: It wouldn't be if you cite the info.  Take a look at [This](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3532/answering-a-question-by-using-information-from-the-web).

Comment: @user301327 said: I don't think these directions for ArchLinux work with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make use of L2TP IPsec VPN package in the repos. It makes things much easier.

`sudo apt-get install l2tp-ipsec-vpn`

Comment: I think he does not need a server, just the client.