# Command line connect to L2TP Windows Server VPN

Tags: 16.04, command-line, vpn

I have been searching for a couple of days not much luck as and everything i come across relies on using the Network Manager UI.

Could someone provide me with a noobish tutorial on how I would configure the ubuntu server to automatically (on startup) connect to an L2TP over IPSec VPN with Windows Login credentials?

It does not have to be L2TP over IPSec, I do also have the Windows Server configured to allow PPTP VPN connections but I would prefer L2TP as it's more secure.

I would also need to know if there is a special configuration I need to prevent the Internet connection being tunneled through the VPN as I know windows does this by default and it has to be turned off on the VPN Network Adapter in windows if the same need to happen on the Ubuntu server I will need to know how to do that so I don't lock myself out of the server by it losing its internet connection :D

The reason for this is that I have quite a lot of attempts on the SSH Port's so I want to set the Hardware Firewall in front of the server to not allow SSH through it and make it so the only way to connect to the SSH server is via the Corporate VPN.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer [this](https://www.elastichosts.com/blog/linux-l2tpipsec-vpn-client/) link to connect L2TP connection. Also in addition to that also check this question & its answer on Ask ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462918/ubuntu-server-connecting-to-l2tp-vpn). As well as [this](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md) Git hub steps to connect L2TP Server as a clinet.

these should do the trick as it did for me, if you face any challenges let me know.

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer that should be edited to contain the important concepts inline.